# Chart refresh avoiding dashboard refresh in pentaho CDE

Tags: pentaho, dashboard, cdf, pentaho-ctools

I'm developing a 3 charts dashboard, with pentaho cde (from community ctools).

The 3 charts are displayed one below the other, so they're not visible to the user unless scroll.

My current problem is that when I want to navigate through the charts in the lower part of the dashboard (for which I have to scroll down first), the events I create make all my dashboard refresh, and therefore I loose my previous scroll down, so I have to scroll down again, or force it grammatically.

Tests lead me into  the thinking that the problem may be the way I create the events.

I've tried

```
Dashboards.fireChange('parameter',variable);
```

or

```
 Dashboards.update(Dashboards.getComponent('myChart'));
```

But no success, both make a kinda scrollTop.

Is there any way to 'navigate' through a chart, and not loosing the scroll?

'Navigate' means to use a chart to show multiple hierarchies, all in the same chart, so as family > subfamily > article, using the clickable / click action options.

Hope you can help me, 
thx in advance.

Comment: A dashboard usually fits to the screen.  Can't you find some way to either fit the screen, or put the other chart(s) on separate pages?  Anyway may be worth asking in forums.pentaho.com as the cde developers tend to hang out there.  Or on IRC ##Pentaho on Freenode.

Comment: I could make a dashboard that fits the screen, but I'll like the other solution. I'll try at pentaho forums, thx!

Comment: you got any solution for these answer. If you got any solution for these. can you provide your answer please.